# Error 'udenfined "paths"' when overwriting gulpfile.js with gulpconfig.json

Tags: json, gulp

I have a gulpfile.js that has default paths set, eg:

```
paths: {
  sass: ['source/style/*.scss', 'source/style/components/**/*.scss'],
}
```

However, I want to work from another directory with slightly different structure and so have set up a gulpconfig.json file with (within that directory):

```
 {
  "site": {
    "dev": "http://localdev.mysite.com",
    "drushAlias": "site",
    "themePrefix": "si",
    "minify": false
  }
  "paths": {
    "sass":["sass/*.scss", "sass/components/**/*.scss"]
  }
}
```

But this gives me an error when I try to run gulp:

```
undefined:8
  "paths": {
  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 152
```

Would anyone know why this could be occurring?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Sorry, that was just part of the JSON file. I've included the whole file above

Comment: You are missing a comma after the } & before "paths"

Comment: @Dijkgraaf right you are. Want to make that an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a comma missing between the } and "paths" making it invalid JSON.  It needs to be as follows.

```
 {
  "site": {
    "dev": "http://localdev.mysite.com",
    "drushAlias": "site",
    "themePrefix": "si",
    "minify": false
  },
  "paths": {
    "sass":["sass/*.scss", "sass/components/**/*.scss"]
  }
}
```